# in ajax data is comming but data not displaying in field

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

```
<script>
function get_customer() {

        $("#customer").html('');
        $("#customer").html('<option value="0">SELECT CUSTOMER</option>');
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?=base_url();?>Drop_downs/get_customer/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(response) {
                $("#customer").append(response);
                console.log(response);
            }

        });

}</script>
```

and this is my html

```
<select name="customer" id="customer" class="form-control select2" required tabindex="1" onFocus="get_customer()">
          <option>SELECT CUSTOMER</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what is your response

Comment: paste your response in your question as well

Comment: Yeah, dude, we need to know what is the response. There should be clearer instructions for new comers before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Response is not an HTML node, so you can not append it. Use `$('#customer').html()` instead.

Comment: But that will overwrite whatever data he got in there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are  receiving  option tag (html code) in response, so you've to use $('#customer').html(response);

Comment: you solution will overwrite the already one default option that's in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function get_customer() {
     $("#customer").html('');
     $("#customer").html('<option value="0">SELECT CUSTOMER</option>');
     $.ajax({
            url: '<?=base_url();?>Drop_downs/get_customer/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                $("#customer").html(response);
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what **'response'** is we won't be able to provide specific help. Nonetheless, the following should help you:

**Adding hard-coded values**

To add a new option to it, with the text "Text 1" displaying in the drop down box, and the value "Value1" being what would be submitted from the form, do this:

```
var select = document.getElementById("customer");
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Text 1', 'Value1');
```

**Adding options from an object**

If you had an object that you wanted to use the property name as the value for the options, and the property value as the text to display, you could do this:

```
var myobject = {
    ValueA : 'Text A',
    ValueB : 'Text B',
    ValueC : 'Text C'
};

var select = document.getElementById("customer");
for(index in myobject) {
    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(myobject[index], index);
}
```

**Note** that while the above is an object, it's often referred to incorrectly as an associative array, even though technically it is not. It can be accessed as an object e.g. myobject.ValueA, or like an array would be e.g. myobject['ValueA']

Now, this code is generic and should hopefully help you achieve what you require. But, if you could update your question with further detail such as what the response is returning, I would be able to be of more help and provide a solution for you.

**Possible JQuery solution:**

If you are using JQuery then it becomes even simpler:

```
$('#customer').append($('<option>', {
    value: 1,
    text: 'My option'
}));
```

If you're adding options from a collection of items, you can do the following:

```
    var myOptions = {
                     val1 : 'Blue',
                     val2 : 'Orange'
                    };
var mySelect = $('#customer');
$.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    mySelect.append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You please provide the console.log(response);
Since I do not know your response I assumed that you have taken customer name in 'customer_name'.Please try the below code.

```
<script>
function get_customer() {
     $("#customer").html('');
     $("#customer").html('<option value="0">SELECT CUSTOMER</option>');
     $.ajax({
            url: '<?=base_url();?>Drop_downs/get_customer/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                var i = 0;
                while (i < data.length)
                    {

                        $('<option>').text(data[i].customer_name).appendTo('#customer');
                        i++;
                    }
            }
        });

}</script>
```